# window.outerWidth VS $(window).outerWidth()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just curious as to what the difference between `window.outerWidth` and `$(window).outerWidth()` is, if any.

I couldn't really find much info about this on Google, so I thought I'd appeal to the masses. This is just a general question, not a specific issue.

Comment: jQuery is javascript...

Comment: JS is the core. jQuery is a library written in JS to simplify actions.

Comment: I meant jQuery vs. traditional JavaScript. Specifically, between those two selectors.

Comment: Luke, use the source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/dimensions.js

Comment: [_This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead._](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Comment: @AlanFoster jQuery is *not* JavaScript.  jQuery is *written* in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jquery's outerWidth](http://jqapi.com/#p=outerWidth):

> Returns the width of the element, along with left and right padding,
>   border, and optionally margin, in pixels.
>
> If includeMargin is omitted or false, the padding and border are
>   included in the calculation; if true, the margin is also included.
>
> **This method is not applicable to window** and document objects; for
>   these, use .width() instead.

[window.outerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.outerWidth):

> window.outerWidth gets the width of the outside of the browser window.
>   It represents the width of the whole browser window including sidebar
>   (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/):

> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead.

So, you should use **$(window).width()**, which returns:

> "width of browser viewport"
>   (so with no window borders and other stuff)

**window.outerWidth** returns whole window width (with borders and other stuff)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/):

> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width) instead.

While [`window.outerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.outerWidth) gets the width of the outside of the browser window, jQuery's [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width) method does return  the width of browser viewport when called on a `window`-selecting jQuery instance. To do this, it calls a bunch of subfunctionsand hooks (see [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/dimensions.js)) to be cross-browser-compatible (but is much slower).

Answer (score 0):

As to the specifics of `outerWidth`:
[jQuery's implementation](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) lets you choose if you want the margin included in the measurement or not.  [Javascript](http://help.dottoro.com/ljjrmtvx.php)'s just gets the number.  I couldn't tell if it included margin or not.

jQuery is just a bunch of fancy JavaScript.  In fact, you can implement anything jQuery does yourself using only JavaScript (and I'd encourage you to do so)!  I'd encourage you to read questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340412/jquery-vs-javascript).