# .width() not giving consistent results

Tags: jquery

I'm getting two different values for the same `selector.width()` and I try to figure out how / why.

Pseudo code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have a link that toggles the width of the list items between `$('#wrapper').width()` and `$(window).width()`. More or less regular view to fullscreen and back. If the `#wrapper` is a fixed width (e.g., `width=500px`) everything is fine.

However, if the wrapper is (for example) `width:50%` then I get unexpected results. The `.width` is fine (read: correct) when I first display the page. That is, prev / next controls etc line up correctly. If I toggle to fullscreen and then come back again to regular view the `.width` value is a couple/few pixels less. I've tried the `width=X%` with different value for `X` and the difference changes. That is, it's not fixed.

Padding and margins are set to zero so I don't think that's it.

Also, I have a `$(window).resize(function()` and if I nudge the window just a bit then the width reading corrects itself. Even if I open Firebug in the bottom is fixes itself.

I understand the pseudo code is vague. I'm just hoping to get some thoughts and direction on how I might be able to pin point where the problem is so I can fix it.

Comment: It is hard to tell, but you should look into position() and offset() properties of parent element as well.

Comment: How is the wrapper laid out (is it positioned, floated, or in flow)?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530237/window-outerwidth-vs-window-outerwidth

Comment: Thx for the help ya all. Best I can tell it had something to with the fact that when in fullscreen the inner contents (using position) are actually wider than the wrapper. I found a fix :) When I went from full to reg I set the width of the inner stuff to 0, get (what is then) the (correct) wrapper width and then set the inner stuff (again) with the correct width. Kinda hack-y I suppose but it works. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .width() pulls the CSS width, rather than *calculated width*, which accounts for padding, borders, etc. To get an element's true width, you should use

```
document.getElementById('myElement').offsetWidth
```

Example, showing the difference in results: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/xixao/DNbqu/</del>

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't seem to contain anything relevant to this conversation.

Comment: It seems the fiddle was somehow hijacked. I don't know what that iframe is about.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I encourage you solve this problem adding/removing a class to the wrapper element that wides the list to 100% not window width.

```
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
}

// on X event
$('#wrapper').addClass('fullscreen');
// on -X event
$('#wrapper').removeClass('fullscreen');
```

If you dont`t follow the previous solution... there are other ways. The problem could be related with [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). That means jQuery could think width is one thing while browser could think is another. In this case I think you should use [$('X').outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) instead of $('X').width().

Again the first solution should be fine.

Cheers!