# Difference between document.getElementByID and jQuery('#id').val?

Tags: javascript, jquery, difference

Dear StackOverflow community,

I am new to jQuery and Javascript, and was wondering what the main differences between these two functions are:

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML      =variable;
```

and

```
jQuery('#id').val(variable);
```

From my understanding, they are two different coding techniques, but when would I use one over the other? and why?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340412/jquery-vs-javascript

Answer (score 3):

The two above examples are slightly different, but not in the way you're expecting.

- `innerHTML` and `.val()` are not equivalent methods.
- jQuery will try to use `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` where appropriate when using the DOM selection `jQuery("SELECTOR")`. These are native methods, so look into them.
- `.val(variable)` will set the **value** of the node found by `jQuery("SELECTOR")` to variable
- `innerHTML = variable` will set the the HTML content of `document.getElementById('id')` to whatever variable is.

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) - Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) - innerHTML sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.

Comment: @user3649082 - Awesome, I'm glad you found it useful =)